# Importing other versions of an Excel Sheet into SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2014

I was wondering whether there might be another way that will allow SQL Server 2014 to import other versions of excel and not only 2007.

Currently my SQL Server is not linked to a datawarehouse whereby I can link the tables and pull data, so therefore extracts are being pulled from the application system and those extracts are imported into SQL Server with Excel 2007. Now the issue is that Excel only allows +-65 000 lines, therefore the rest if the data is not importing into Excel.

I have tried to convert the file to a txt format but due to the different format of each field, the data gets 'scrammed' and is not pulled correctly into the columns.

SQL Server only allows for a Excel 2007 version to be imported, is there another way to import an Excel worksheet as that will allow me to pull in lines more than 65 000 or is there perhaps another way to go about it.

(the txt file does not work).

Comment: Excel 2007 should allow more lines than 65'000. That was the limit for Excel 2003.

Comment: Yes your right, sorry about that, I can only save it in 97-2003 version. So basically all i have to do is get 2007 Excel? Will SQL allow for 2007 or an even later version?

Comment: I get the following error when importing an Excel 2007 sheet: 'The Microsoft.ACD.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. (System Data)'' I don't have any additional programs loaded except for SQL. Currently we use SQL to run queries manually. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: I managed to figure out what to do. I just had to download http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=23734 and its wroking.